# macro replacement

Tags: c, linux, macros

I write the following codes:

```
#define GATE(name, num)do{\
  name##list[num] = #name;\
}while(0)

char* name[] = {"hello", "world", "byebye"};

int i;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    GATE(name[i],0);
}
```

---

Obviously, I can't get what I want that `GATE(name[0],0)` is replaced by `hellolist[0] = "hello"`, but `name[0]list[0] = "hello"`, which can lead a gcc error.

I want to know how can I make what I want using macro?

Comment: Are you sure a macro is the best option? Why not use a function?

Comment: Macros run during compilation, not during execution.

Comment: In this example, they are both available, but in some conditions, macro is convinient.

Answer (score 5):

No, this can't be done. The preprocessor does text replacement before the compiler kicks in. So the preprocessor *never actually sees the string "hello"* - thus it can't emit `hellolist`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do what you wanted in the manner in which you'd intended.  However, by modifying the macro I believe the you can get what you wanted.  Try the following:

```
#define GATE(source_arr, source_index, list_index)do{\
  source_arr##list[list_index] = source_arr[source_index];\
  }while(0)    

char *name[] = {"hello", "world", "byebye"};

int i;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  GATE(name, i, 0);
}
```

Note that this still won't copy the literal text (e.g. "hello") out of the source array - it will instead simply copy a pointer (I'm assuming that namelist is an array of pointers).  If you need "hello", etc to be constant you might want to modify the delaration of `name` to include `const`.  Also note that I modified the title of the first argument to the GATE macro to avoid confusion with the like-named variable.  Hopefully this helps.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessing is done first before compilation, so your expected output will not appear as mentioned by cnicutar above.

To understand what is happening exactly, you can run your file with "-E" option in gcc and /E option with MSVC compilers and see the preprocessor output.